# Javascript document.ready repeat in loop (Without DRY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, for-loop

I have an HTML code that contains 3 groups of radio buttons. each group has an active class in its images section. (In fact Active-1, Active-2 and Active-2 in the Image tag)

```
<!-------- Select Color ---------->
<div class="color-0">
<!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-0" id="navy-blue-0" name="color-0" value="navy-blue-0" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-0" id="aqua-0" name="color-0" value="aqua-0">
        <label for="aqua-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-0" id="pink-0" name="color-0" value="pink-0">
        <label for="pink-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="color-1">
    <!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-1" id="navy-blue-1" name="color" value="navy-blue-1" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-1" id="aqua-1" name="color-1" value="aqua-1">
        <label for="aqua-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-1" id="pink-1" name="color-1" value="aqua-1">
        <label for="pink-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="color-2">
    <!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-2" id="navy-blue-2" name="color-2" value="navy-blue-2" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-2" id="aqua-2" name="color-2" value="aqua-2">
        <label for="aqua-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-2" id="pink-2" name="color-2" value="aqua-2">
        <label for="pink-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>


<!-------- Show Image ---------->

<div class="img-0">
    <!--- Active-0 --->
    <img class="img-fluid active-0" data-image="navy-blue-0" src="img/img-navy-blue-0.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="aqua-0" src="img/img-aqua-0.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="pink-0" src="img/img-pink-0.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="red-0" src="img/img-red-0.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="white-0" src="img/img-white-0.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="img-1">
    <!--- Active-1 --->

    <img class="img-fluid active-1" data-image="navy-blue-1" src="img/img-navy-blue-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="aqua-1" src="img/img-aqua-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="pink-1" src="img/img-pink-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="red-1" src="img/img-red-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="white-1" src="img/img-white-1.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="img-2">
    <!--- Active-2 --->
    <img class="img-fluid active-2" data-image="navy-blue-2" src="img/img-navy-blue-2.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="aqua-2" src="img/img-aqua-2.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="pink-2" src="img/img-pink-2.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="red-2" src="img/img-red-2.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" data-image="white-2" src="img/img-white-2.png" alt="">
</div>
```

The problem now is that I had to write code three times in the JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.color-0 input').on('click', function () {
        var x = $(this).attr('data-image');
        $('.active-0').removeClass('active-0');
        $('.img-0 img[data-image = ' + x + ']').addClass('active-0');
        $(this).addClass('active-0');
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.color-1 input').on('click', function () {
        var x = $(this).attr('data-image');
        $('.active-1').removeClass('active-1');
        $('.img-1 img[data-image = ' + x + ']').addClass('active-1');
        $(this).addClass('active-1');
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.color-2 input').on('click', function () {
        var x = $(this).attr('data-image');
        $('.active-2').removeClass('active-2');
        $('.img-2 img[data-image = ' + x + ']').addClass('active-2');
        $(this).addClass('active-2');
    });
});
```

So I tried using loops but the code didn't work. like this:

```
var shoePart = [0, 1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < shoePart.length; i++) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.color-' + shoePart[i] + ' input').on('click', function () {
            var x = $(this).attr('data-image');
            $('.active-' + shoePart[i]).removeClass('active-' + shoePart[i]);
            $('.img-' + shoePart[i] + ' img[data-image = ' + x + ']').addClass('active-' + shoePart[i]);
            $(this).addClass('active-' + shoePart[i]);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the CSS to the question, as it seems relevant to the problem. Also, is `img-aqua-0.png` the same as `img-aqua-1.png` and `img-aqua-2.png`? These should be genericised if so.

Comment: Wrap all your code into a single `ready` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a common class on all three tags and an attribute of number. Then can call your `jQuery` on that as below:

```
<!-------- Select Color ---------->
<div class="color-0 common-color" attr-number="0">
<!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-0" id="navy-blue-0" name="color-0" value="navy-blue-0" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-0" id="aqua-0" name="color-0" value="aqua-0">
        <label for="aqua-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-0" id="pink-0" name="color-0" value="pink-0">
        <label for="pink-0"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="color-1 common-color" attr-number="1">
    <!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-1" id="navy-blue-1" name="color" value="navy-blue-1" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-1" id="aqua-1" name="color-1" value="aqua-1">
        <label for="aqua-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-1" id="pink-1" name="color-1" value="aqua-1">
        <label for="pink-1"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="color-2 common-color" attr-number="2">
    <!--- Checked --->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="navy-blue-2" id="navy-blue-2" name="color-2" value="navy-blue-2" checked>
        <label for="navy-blue-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="aqua-2" id="aqua-2" name="color-2" value="aqua-2">
        <label for="aqua-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-image="pink-2" id="pink-2" name="color-2" value="aqua-2">
        <label for="pink-2"><span></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then can call `jQuery` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.common-color input').on('click', function () {
        var x = $(this).attr('data-image');
        var elemCounter = $(this).closest(".common-color").attr("attr-number");
        $('.active-'+elemCounter).removeClass('active-'+elemCounter);
        $('.img-'+ elemCounter +' img[data-image = ' + x + ']').addClass('active-'+elemCounter);
        $(this).addClass('active-'+elemCounter);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you!!